# C++ Class converting Object to Integer

Tags: c++, integer

I'm self learning C++ from a book (Schaums Programming with c++) and i've come across something i want to try but it doesn't cover(as fair as i can tell).

I have a class that contains `hrs`:`mins`:`secs`. 
Is it possible to write a type conversion that will return the Object in form of a total as an integer?

If not that may be why i can not find anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, you just have to write a cast operator. Assuming you want to convert your time to seconds:

```
class MyTime
{
    ...

public:
    operator int() const
    {
        return hours_ * 3600 + minutes_ * 60 + seconds_;
    }
}
```

In C++11 you can also add the keyword `explicit` to your operator so that your cast will explicitly require a `static_cast<int>` in order to compile.

Comment: It is better to make it `explicit operator int()` in C++11, alternatively `int HashCode()` or something.

Comment: @Nawaz Yeah, `HashCode` would be a really intuitive name for a function that returns time duration in seconds :P

Comment: @Praetorian: It is not *seconds*, it just happens to be *seconds*. there is a difference. Also, if he really wants to convert *time* into *seconds*, then he wouldn't have asked the question, as he (probably) knows that already (I guess). Also, in that case `operator int()` would surely not make sense.

Comment: Yes, my object is indeed a Duration hrs:mins:secs. @NolwennLeGuen Ah i see. So you don't have to pass it the object/parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a time duration with a resolution of seconds, then yes -- something like `hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds` should give you an integer number of seconds in the duration.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to convert your class to the desired integer value you want. The typecast methods can be overloaded. See here: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/910-overloading-typecasts/